# Show that the subset of a real ordered field defined by a ring formula has a least upper bound.

Tags: real-analysis, logic, field-theory, model-theory, real-numbers

So currently trying to get well practiced in model theory, and i have come across the following question which i need some help with.

Esentially let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a non empty set, bounded above defined by an $L_{oring}$ formula $\phi(x)$. Suppose also that $<F;+,.,0,1,<     >$ is another real closed field. Show that the subset of F that is defined by $\phi(x)$ also has a least upper bound.

Literally no idea where to begin. Heeeeelp!!

Comment: Long time ago, but if you were satisfied with my answer from below, it would be nice if you accept it (that's the common practice here on stackexchange)...

Answer (score 2):

Note that the theory of real closed fields is complete. This means that any two real closed fields are elementarily equivalent. You can use these facts to solve your problem: Since the subset defined by $\phi(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded from above, it must have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$ (this follows from the ordering completeness of the ordered field $\mathbb{R}$). Now, you have to verify that the statement

$\phantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}$"the set defined by $\phi(x)$ has a least upper bound"

can be formalized by a sentence in the language of ordered rings. Assume $\psi$ is the corresponding sentence. Then, because of my previous remarks, $\mathbb{R} \vDash \psi$ and since two real closed fields are elementarily equivalent, it follows that $F \vDash \psi$.

$\textbf{Edit}:$ Here is a hint concerning the formalization of the above statement. Start with
$$\exists x[\forall  y(\phi(y) \to (y<x \vee y=x)) \wedge \phantom{a}...\phantom{a}]$$
This formula expresses that there is an upper bound $x$ for the set defined by $\phi$. Now, try to complete this formula such that it expresses that $x$ is also a least upper bound.

Comment: Thats brilliant, that makes sense. How can we formalize the statement into a sentence in the language of ordered rings though? Sorry this is all pretty new to me,

Comment: $\exists x \forall y [ \phi(x) > \phi(y)]$ and $\exists z \forall y [ \phi(z) > \phi(y) \rightarrow \phi(x) > \phi(y)]$    does that work?

Comment: pretty sure something is going to be wrong here but ive gone for;

$\exists z (\phi(z))$ and $z<x \rightarrow (y<z$ or $y=z) ]$ ? is that close?

Comment: ok so could i call the above formula $\psi$ and then my finished formula would be $ \psi(x,y) \wedge \forall z[\psi(z) \rightarrow x<z$ or $x=z$ would that all be ok now?

Comment: @ENAFMTH: Please excuse my rather confusing comments. (I found it somewhat difficult to communicate via the comments). I edited my answer and hope the things are now a bit clearer.

Comment: Your new approach seems much better. In fact it seems to be nearly correct. If you write down the whole formula you have in mind, I simply can check it.

Comment: $\exists x [ \forall y [(\phi(y) \rightarrow (y<x$ or $y=x)] \wedge \forall z[ (\phi(y) \rightarrow (y<z$ or $y=z)) \rightarrow x<z$ or $x=z]]$

Comment: This looks quite correct. But I think you should insert an additional quantifier $\forall y$ behind $\forall z[$. Then it should work.